# Finding number of instances of exact word of "x" in text

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm working c# to find out number of instances of exact word of "x".
For example:

```
List<string> words = new List<string> {"Mode", "Model", "Model:"};
Text= "This is Model: x Type: y aa: e";
```

I've used Regex:

```
for(i=0; i<words.count; i++)
{
    word= list[i]
    int count= Regex.Matches(Text,word) 
}
```

But its not working. The result of above code gave `count=1` for every `Mode`, `Model`, and `Model:`.
I want to have my count to be `0` for `Mode`, `0` for `Model`, but `1` for `Model:` that it finds the number of instance of exact word.

**Forgot that I can't use split in my case. Is there any way I can get not using `split`?**

Comment: I suggested a Regex solution if you don't want to use LINQ or `Split`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use LINQ for this purpose:

```
List<string> words = new List<string> { "Mode", "Model", "Model:" };
Text = "This is Model: x Type: Model: y aa: Mode e Model:";
var textArray = Text.Split(' ');
var countt = words.Select(item => textArray.ToList().Contains(item) ? 
             textArray.Count(d => d == item) : 0).ToArray();
```

Result:

> For Mode => count = 1
>
> For Model => count = 0
>
> For Model: => count = 3

**EDIT:** I prefer to use LINQ for this purpose because as you see it is more easier and cleaner in this scenario, but if you are looking for a Regex solution yet you could try this:

```
List<int> count = new List<int>();
foreach (var word in words)
{
    var regex = new Regex(string.Format(@"\b{0}(\s|$)", word), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    count.Add(regex.Matches(Text).Count);
}
```

**EDIT2:** Or by combining LINQ and Regex and without `Split` you can:

```
List<int> count = words.Select(word => new Regex(string.Format(@"\b{0}(\s|$)", word), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                               .Select(regex => regex.Matches(Text).Count).ToList();
```

Comment: That's ok now for me. My +1 :)

Comment: @Pikoh It could be more cleaner without using `foreach` see the updated answer again.

Comment: Much better indeed. Great answer ;)

Comment: @S.Akbari I had just posted my answer making it linq too... it's a bit different than yours, so I'll keep it there, but +1

Comment: Hi S.Akbari, 
Can I ask you one more question? 
I've used this, and it worked really well. But I faced one more problem.
If one of the element in words = {"Generator (1100)", "(1100)", "13Generator"} it gave me an false result.
Is there any way to solve that problem? I know it failed because first word is not letter and last word is not space. But Please let me know if you have solution. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Although @S.Akhbari 's solution works... I think using Linq is cleaner:

```
var splitted = Text.Split(' ');
var items = words.Select(x => new { Word = x, Count = splitted.Count(y => y == x) });
```

Each `item` will have `Word` and `Count` properties.

[See it in action here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NdP5eT)

Comment: Its really good solution, but I can't use split for my case.
Is there any other way not using split?

Answer (score 0):

`\b` matches on word boundaries.

```
 for(i=0; i<words.count; i++)
 {
     word= list[i] 
     var regex = new Regex(string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", word), 
                      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
     int count= regex.Matches(Text).Count; 
  }
```

Comment: Good solution but not complete yet. For example if text is:`Text = "This is Model Model: x Type: Model: y aa: Mode e Model:";` I got `1`,`4`,`0` instead of `1`,`1`,`3`.